# Will network adapter settings be shared in a Windows 10 dual boot?

Tags: windows, boot, network-adapter, dualboot

For a couple of reasons, I am considering a dual boot of Windows 10. One of those reasons is that I would like one of the boots to be an "Internet" boot with the ethernet adapter enabled, and the other to be an Internet-free boot with the ethernet adapter disabled except when necessary.

My question is, would the adapter settings be shared between the two copies of Windows? That is, if I have the ethernet adapter enabled on one partition with one copy of windows, will the other partition with the second copy of windows necessarily have the ethernet adapter enabled as well? The same question goes for disabling.

The primary account I would use on both partitions would be a standard acct, while the admin acct passwords are stored with a close friend. So, I could not change this on the fly, and this is intentional.

My assumption is that the network adapter settings--or indeed any control panel settings--are not shared between copies of Windows 10 on different partitions. Please tell me if I am correct or not.

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your assumption is correct.  The adapter would be enabled in one and disabled in the other if they're genuinely different OS installs.

Be aware that there are other considerations, however. Such as wake-on-lan and IMEI, which operate at the hardware layer and do not require the operating system to be specifically configured to provide much of their features. If your BIOS/UEFI is configured to allow WOL, for example, then when your computer is turned off, if it receives a WOL trigger it will boot into the default OS, even if that OS is the one with the network adapter disabled.